# Web Service method over loading or default parameters

Tags: webservices, apex-webservice

I have a web service method to load invoices into Salesforce for product type A and I am trying to modify the same method for product type B invoices. However the Product type B has couple more parameters than product type A. We cannot change the client side call for product type A as it requires a lot of change process. I see that we cannot overload a webservice method and Salesforce does not allow defaulting a method parameter.

Code:

```
webservice static String createInvoice( String invoiceNumber,String invoiceType,Decimal Amount, String invoiceCurrency,String ProductType,String customerAccountNo, Date invoiceDate, String invoiceMonth,Date paymentDueDate, Decimal volume){
    Invoice__c invoice = new Invoice__c();
    invoice.Invoice_Number__c = invoiceNumber;
    invoice.Invoice_Type__c = invoiceType;
    other value assignments....
    insert invoice;
    if(invoice.Id != null){
        return invoice.Id;
    }
    else{
        return error;
    }
}
```

Can you please suggest an alternative please?

Comment: Could you provide code or examples?  One method to do this is have two webservice methods, and call the type B method from the type A method - The product A would call a simpler version, and then call the type B method with default arguments.  This could also be done if they shared the same underlying private method.

Comment: webservice static String createInvoice( String invoiceNumber,String invoiceType,Decimal Amount, String invoiceCurrency,String ProductType,String customerAccountNo, Date invoiceDate, String invoiceMonth,Date paymentDueDate, Decimal volume){
 Invoice__c invoice                  = new Invoice__c();
 invoice.Invoice_Number__c           = invoiceNumber;
        invoice.Invoice_Type__c         = invoiceType;
 other value assignments.... 
      insert invoice;
        if(invoice.Id != null){
            return invoice.Id;
        }else{
            return error;
  }}

Comment: can I create another web service call lets say createInvoice_ProdB and inside it can I call createInvoices method directly?

Comment: Yes - You can do that.